# It works when loaded from file, but not when typed into ghci. Why?

Tags: haskell, ghci

If I put the following 2 lines into foobar.hs

```
f 1 = 1
f x = f (x-1)
```

then

```
$ ghci
> :load foobar.hs
> f 5
1
```

but if I do

```
$ ghci
> let f 1 = 1
> let f x = f (x-1)
> f 5
^CInterrupted.
```

then it does not return. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter binding overrides the former. Use this in ghci:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let f 1 = 1
Prelude|     f x = f (x-1)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> f 5
1
```

Or, without the layout:

```
Prelude> let f 1 = 1; f x = f (x-1)
Prelude> f 5
1
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter it all in on one line, or using `:{` and `:}` to enter multiple lines:

```
> let { f 1 = 1; f x = f (x - 1) }
```

Or

```
> :{
>   let f 1 = 1
>       f x = f (x - 1)
>   :}
```

When you use two `let` statements to define `f`, you are actually redefining `f` the second time, not adding to its definition.  If you were to do

```
> let x = 1
> let x = 5
```

Then, `x` would be 5, not 1.  The same goes for functions.  First, you define `f` as `f 1 = 1`.  Next, you define `f` as `f x = f (x - 1)`, which overwrites the previous definition for `f`.

Comment: There's also GHCi's multi-line syntax, toggled with `:set +m`/`:unset +m`; after a let, if you indent by four spaces (for alignment) on the next line, you can keep defining in the same let block.