# Why does this function work in runghc but not in ghci?

Tags: haskell

If I run the following file:

```hs
ll []     = 0
ll (x:xs) = 1 + ll xs
main = putStrLn (show (ll [2,2,2]))
```

using runghc, it works and prints 3.

In ghci, otoh, I get:

```
ghci> let ll [] = 0
ghci> let ll (x:xs) = 1 + ll xs
ghci> ll [3,4,43,9]
*** Exception: <interactive>:23:5-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function ll
```

What's the reason the above code fails to work in ghci?  What changes are needed to make it work?

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19210660/791604) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19231915/791604). Seems to be a very common question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running ghci, everything you type is in the IO monad, hence you need the extra `let`s (which you did include).  However this leads to a complication.

Each time you use "let", you are redefining the function.  The only one that counts is the last one

```
let ll (x:xs) = 1 + ll xs
```

so you are missing the other case

```
let ll [] = 0
```

You can define both on the same line however, like this

```
let ll [] = 0; ll (x:xs) = 1 + ll xs
```

Comment: You can also use `:{ ` and `:}` to make multiline definitions.

Comment: You can also use `:set +m` to enable multi-line input, but you must remember to indent your code.  Hit return a couple times to finish the block.